# How to check for PHP session from login page

Tags: php, html, authentication, session, redirect

I have two pages made in PHP, index (using it as login page) and main page (this one should be protected). 
Index page has a login form that asks only for password (there are no users intended to be).

I want to make this:
1. When you enter password on index page, and if it's correct, the site will redirect you to the main page. If password is not correct then it will alert you about that.
2. Main page should not be visible if you have not entered password on the index page. If you have entered it then you will be able to see the main page.

I figured out that the easiest way would be to make it with PHP session check, but it's not working on my code, so can you please help me?

So this is my PHP code for the index page. Here the site needs to check is (universal, for all) password correct, and if so it needs to redirect to main, or if not to display some alert box.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $password = '1234';

    if($_POST['password'] == $password){
        //Create session
            $_SESSION['session'] = 1;


        // If correct redirect to main
            header('Location: http://www.example.com/main');
            exit;
    }
    else {
        // If not correct stay on index (do nothing)
    }
?>
```

Code my main page looks like this. This is where the site should check if user has session and then decide should he be able to see the site or not (if not it should redirect to index for login).

```
<?php 
session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION["session"]))
   {
      header("location: http://example.com/index");
   }
?>
```

I Googled everything and came out with no working solution. Is there better way to achive this or can you help me fix it?
So TLDR, how to password protect main page with login (no users, same password for everyone)?

Currently this code doesn't work. When I enter password on index it redirects to main. But main page doesn't have session check working. It simply shows all without redirecting to index for login if user is without session.

Comment: You don't tell us what is going wrong, or what it is doing wrong? What is actually happening?

Comment: Where is POST getting its data from?

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited post. Currently this code doesn't work. When I enter password on index it redirects to main. But main page doesn't have session check working. It simply shows all without redirecting to index for login if user is without session.

Comment: POST is getting data from this form

Comment: <form action="" method="post">
                            <input class="upisnopolje" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Unesite kod" required><input class="upisnopolje"  id="upisnopoljefix" type="submit" value="Ok">
                        </form>

Comment: You need an `exit` after your `header` call in main. Also, you only check if the session index is set, not that the value is `1`. How are you going about testing this without login? Clearing cookies?

Comment: I added exit and it the main page redirects to the login page, but it redirects all the time, even when I enter password and access it via direct link. I suspect that the reason for that is beacuse I havn't made it check for value. How can I do that? Sorry for newbie questions, I'm currently learing php. Testing it with clearing cookis, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. sorry for my first advice. It is obviously not a solution. But if i understand you correctly. This is my working approach:

**index.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();
$password = '1234';

// Check if the user is not already logged in
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    header('Location: main.php');
}

// Check if the form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($_POST['password'] == $password) {
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        header('Location: main.php');
    }
}
?>
```

with form

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <input class="upisnopolje" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Unesite kod" required>
    <input class="upisnopolje" id="upisnopoljefix" type="submit" name="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

**main.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();

// Check if user is logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION["login"])) {
    header("location: index.php");
}

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    unset($_SESSION["login"]);
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>
```

with form to logout

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log out">
</form>
```

*Note that submit button needs to have `name="submit"` for `$_POST['submit']` check.*

Hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks man, it's working like a charm. You saved me! Just one question, if I decide to have more pages (like the main one), can I use the same code from the main.php or I need to edit something before using it on another page?

Comment: Check if login key is set in session (`isset($_SESSION["login"]`) is all you need for another pages.